# Incoherence Program header and sector header

Tags: elf

I am facing an issue with a file generated with a tool with gcc in background , the output file is an elf file with a segment in program header that doesn't exist in sector header.
exp : in sector header the segment is at address : `0x08001000` but in program header the segment is at `0x08000000` (no segment in sector header with this address ).
I need to understand is it normal? is the file to be treated like a bad file or normally treated.

[Here is the section header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbpce.png)
[And here is the bad program header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95SBN.png)

Comment: You _might_ get a useful answer if you show the output from `readelf -WS` and `readelf -Wl` and the linker script (if any) that was used to link this binary. Sections aren't necessary in the final executable _at all_, so lack of a section starting at `0x08000000` isn't necessarily a problem.

Comment: I updated the question with content of program header and section header. Unfortunately I don't have the linker script . 
The reality is that there is no section at 0x08000000  but there is a section at 0x08000100
and the program header is adding this extra rong segment at 0x08000000 instead of the correct segment at 0x08000100

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste the text itself.

Comment: Your binary looks _completely_ normal. You don't appear to have any problem to solve here.

Comment: How is it normal when there is a segment in program header that doesn't exist in section header ?